# Sum and Trim Down DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum, mschart, delete-row

I have a datagridview that looks like the following:

```
Day          Duration (mins)

Monday        2

Monday        3

Monday        4

Tuesday       3 

Tuesday       5

Tuesday       2
```

Is it possible that I do summation for the duration, and then trim down similar days into a single row, that looks like the following?

```
Day          Duration (mins)

Monday        9

Tuesday       10
```

The reason behind doing this is because that I want to plot the results onto the graph of Duration vs Day of Week. You might question the odd data collection that I have, but I have another column where the time of the day is populated, which is not needed in this case, so I omitted it.

I just want the total duration of the day be added up before I plot them up into the chart. Probably going in the wrong direction, but any pointer would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReportViewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) control.

> ReportViewer is a freely redistributable control that enables embedding reports in applications developed using the .NET Framework.

or you can use [DataGridView.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) property and use any collection as a DataSource for DataGridView.